# Get path with optional values

Tags: regex

I have the following values:

```
1/
1/2/
1/2/3/
1/3/5/8/
1/3/5/8/10
1/3/5/8/10/15
```

How can I create a regular expression where the first two parts of the path (`1/A/`) *must* be included, and the max length it should fetch should be of the form `1/A/B/C/`, but can also be just `1/A/`, `1/A/B/` or `1/A/B/C/`. Anything longer should not be included.

These are the values that *should* work:

```
1/2/
1/2/3/
1/3/5/8/
```

Comment: Doesn't `1/` violate the rule *"the first two parts of the path (1/A/) must be included"*. ? Anyways, what have you tried so far? This is not McRegex where you can just order an expression.

Comment: @FelixKling My apologies. That's what I get for copying and pasting. I updated the question.

Comment: You should try something before asking. [regex101](https://regex101.com/), for example, is a very useful tool.

Comment: You have to determine what the valid path characters are, then `(?:[pathchars]*/){m,n}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

`^(\w+/){m,n}$`

where *m* and *n* are integers representing the lower and higher bounds of how many slashes deep the path should go.